# CMake: How to add custom generic compilation rule?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I need to compile protocol buffer .proto files to .pb.cc,.pb.h files. There is a program for this conversion.

```
protoc test.proto --cpp_out .
```

How can I add such a generic rule in cmake? I can do this with add_custom_command. But I have to this for every .proto file. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Fraser's answer is correct, please acknowledge it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like CMake's [`FindProtobuf`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#module%3aFindProtobuf) module provides this functionality via the function `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP`.

You can pass multiple .proto files in the one call, e.g.

```
file(GLOB ProtoFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.proto")
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(ProtoSources ProtoHeaders ${ProtoFiles})
```

Note that even though the CMakeLists.txt file which calls `find_package(Protobuf)` could be the top-level one, the CMakeLists.txt file(s) which invoke the function would need to be in the same directory as the .proto files.

Comment: Just to expand, ${ProtoSources} and ${ProtoHeaders} are then variables which contain the <filename>.pb.cc and <filename>.pb.h files, respectively. They can be used directly in the add_library() and add_executable() functions.